# How can I change the title of the Home link in the navigation bar?

Tags: theme-development, menus, pages, title, homepage

I use [Bones](https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones) theme with a static front page. The header.php calls the `bones_main_nav()` function without parameters, while `bones_main_nav()` only calls the [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function.

Comment: Do you have any menus defined in Appearance -> Menus?

Comment: @PatJ No, I haven't touched that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_nav_menu` with no arguments and no menus defined in the back end at `wp-admin->Appearance->Menus` (which sounds like the circumstance you describe) just lists your pages, plus a "Home" link.

That is done by calling [`wp_page_menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu), the default callback for `wp_nav_menu`, which means that under those conditions you can alter that text by hooking to [`wp_page_menu_args`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L890) and setting, or changing, the `show_home` argument.

```
function alter_default_home_link_wpse_1011444($args) {
  $args['show_home'] = 'Home is where the heart is';
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'alter_default_home_link_wpse_1011444');
```